# What are different type of state management technique?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net web application.I am very much confused about the state management technique as in which state management technique is good.

I need to understand :

How to choose one of the state management mechanism?

Which is the most efficient and most recommended ?

What are the security concerns to be taken care of while using one of them.

Comment: It depends on what kind of state you need. What is your main goal with this state? Is it like a web session, or a state during a sequence of activities?

Comment: Honestly speaking, only you can answer your own question based on _your applications' (specific) requirements_ . See [MSDN guidance/options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7(v=vs.100).aspx). Hth

Answer (score 1):

The approach you want to take depends on the scenario.
For instance, if you have a web farm scenario, you will need a state server[(
http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/07/01/web-farms-in-net-and-iis-part-5-session-state-management/)](http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/07/01/web-farms-in-net-and-iis-part-5-session-state-management/)
Or if you want hot your application in Azure, you session state is a bit different that hosting it on-prem...
So you see you will have different options based on what you are building...

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a few different state management techniques (assuming a browser app).

They include (but are not limited to) View state, Control state, Session state and Application State. Session state can also be configured in a number of different ways.

Which of these (or other) options you choose depend on factors such as the type of data you want to store, the lifetime and scope of the data and, in the case of Session state, your architecture (if you are using load balancing etc..)